# Can I run Vulkano PC Player on Windows without being administrator?

Tags: windows, uac, video-streaming

Whenever I run Vulkano PC Player (or the Belkin @TV player) on Windows, it gives me a UAC prompt requesting administrator privileges.  This seems gratuitous for a streaming video client.  Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this seems to work.

1. Download and install [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).
2. Run Resource Hacker.  From its menu, choose **File > Open** and select `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Monsoon Multimedia\Vulkano\PC Player\Vulkano PC Player.exe"`. (`%ProgramFiles(x86)%` will usually be `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` for most people.)
3. A tree listing the embedded resources of `:Vulkano PC Player.exe"` should appear in Resource Hacker's left pane.  Navigate to find the **Manifest > 1: 1033** resource.
4. You should see a bunch of XML.  Remove the following (note that I've reformatted the indentation here for readability:

---

```
<asmv3:trustInfo xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:security>
        <asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
            <asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">
            </asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel>
        </asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
    </asmv3:security>
</asmv3:trustInfo>
```

(Alternatively, that section could be commented out with `<!--` and `-->`.)

As of version Vulkano PC Player version 1.8.3.129, the resulting XML should look like (ignoring indentation differences):

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.MFC" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50608.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.4053" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
            </assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

5. From Resource Hacker's menu, choose **Action > Modify**.  This compiles the modified resource.
6. From Resource Hacker's menu, choose **File > Save As**.  Save the modified file somewhere. (Note that you will not be able to overwrite the original `"Vulkano PC Player.exe"` file directly if you don't already have administrator privileges.)
7. Open the `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Monsoon Multimedia\Vulkano\PC Player\"` folder.  Make a backup copy of `"Vulkano PC Player.exe"`.
8. In Explorer, move the new `"Vulkano PC Player.exe"` file from step 6 into the `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Monsoon Multimedia\Vulkano\PC Player\"` folder.

The `asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel` part of the application manifest tells Windows to require administrator privileges when running the program (and therefore to show a UAC prompt if necessary).  As far as I can tell, Vulkano PC Player seems to run fine without it (and I don't see why it should have ever needed it).

Doing equivalent steps on the Belkin @TV player (`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Belkin\@TV\PC Player\PC Player.exe"`) should work too.